# Content > Pages not loading in the back end of Magento 2.1.7

Tags: magento2, backend, cms-pages

[image]

Recently we have been experiencing issues when trying to access pages on the back end, the page just doesn't load.

We have tried multiple browsers (IE, Chrome, Firefox, Safari) and this had made no difference. This issue has only started happening in the last couple of days.

I'm relatively new to working with websites and this is the first major issues I've encountered.

Comment: are you get any error logs

Comment: @Rajkumar.E I am not getting any error logs.

Comment: are you reindex, you database, if not run this command `php bin/magento indexer:reindex` then check it.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for?

main.CRITICAL: exception 'Magento\Framework\Exception\FileSystemException' with message 'Cannot read contents from file "/home/buyprint7/public_html/pub/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto/en_AU/mage/requirejs/mixins.js" Warning!file_get_contents(/home/buyprint7/public_html/pub/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto/en_AU/mage/requirejs/mixins.js): failed to open stream: No such file or directory' in /home/buyprint7/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Driver/File.php:149

Comment: Same like your some controller return with html content, I gest that is error alert.

Answer (score 1):

There are many cases which can result in same issue

First delete follow folders in Magento root:

```
var/cache
var/di
var/generation
var/view_preprocessed
var/page_cache
var/log
pub/static/adminhtml
pub/static/_requirejs/adminhtml
```

If you are in development stage then turn on developer mode by applying below mentioned command from Magento CLI:

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

If you are in production mode then run below command in terminal:

```
php bin\magento deploy:mode:set production
php bin\magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Lastly, refresh admin/backend and frontend page

Comment: Thank you @Ananth for your reply.

Unfortunately, I'm still experiencing the same issue even after following those steps.

Comment: Hi, can you let us know your magento version, OS, version, php version

Comment: @anath 2.1.7 Current PHP version:  5.6

Comment: I think some extension problem is there, can you disable third party extensions and check again (**Note:** before checking do as my answer)

Comment: @Kdiz Can we talk on Skype?

Answer (score 0):

You files are not accessible in pub folder. So please Put file permission for below folders

```
root dir >chmod -R 0777 var/ pub/
```

then reload the page ctrl+R.

Comment: I have done this and I'm still having the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create static-content with specific language

clear all in

```
 <mage-root> rm -rf var/*
 <mage-root> rm -rf pub/static/* (not .htaccess)
 <mage-root> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_AU
 <mage-root> php bin/magento cache:clean
```

if you want debug info

```
 <mage-root> php bin/magento -vv setup:static-content:deploy en_AU
```

Then Clear Cache, then check it. make sure you need to put right folder and file permission.

Reference: 
  https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2065

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/prereq/file-system-perms.html

Comment: Hi @Rajkumar .E This didn't resolve the issues. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the following steps

1) Delete the "di" folder located in var directory

2) Run this command in project root folder `command:cd /yourmagentoroot/bin`

3) Then run this command sudo ./magento setup:di:compile

4) Finally give file/directory permissions.

**Source :** http://blog.trimantra.com/error-magento-2-upgrade-command/

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't fix the issue. Thank you

Comment: Okey i will check and provide the best one :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're a Windows user. After struggle of weeks I got the solution. I hope it will help you people as well.
Please follow the steps:

1. First of all give permission to your directory of project using

> takeown /F C:\xampp\htdocs{your_project_name}

2. Secondly, Flush the cache

   > php bin/magento cache:flush
3. Then, perform reindexing

   > php bin/magento indexer:reindex
4. Finally, deploy static content and you're done

   > php -dmemory_static=6G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

Use -f in deploying static content if you're in developer mode.